# SharePoint List with many columns

Tags: list, site-column

We are designing a system where data from forms will be stored in sharepoint lists.

Problem is that these lists can have very many columns.

Question is:

- Is there a max number of columns in a sharepoint list?
- Can we use reporting services to read from two lists?
- Is it possible to display information from two lists in a single view even if the combined is over the max number of columns

Comment: Please try to ask **only one** question in a question. This is the best fit for our system and means your posts will be easier to find for other people in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Q: Is there a max number of columns in a sharepoint list?**
A: [SharePoint Server 2010 capacity management: Software boundaries and limits / Column limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.14%29.aspx#Column)

**Q: Can we use reporting services to read from two lists?**
A: Yes: if you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 reporting service

**Q: Is it possible to display information from two lists in a single view even if the combined is over the max number of columns**
A: yes by using LookUp field to the other list and select the columns you want to show, then in the View select the columns you want.

Answer (score 1):

Please take into account, that due to SharePoint Data architecture each column added to your list will also add N rows to a list items table in a Content DB (where N is items number in that list). And if you are adding Index to the colum, this also adds N rows to the index table in your Content DB.
Thus Max number of columns could be dictated by Content DB size.